Push Custom metrics in google cloud-run
I run a cron-job in google cloud-run and want to create some custom-metrics from it.
This is reworked legacy system which previously used prometheus to relay custom-metrics to a Dashboard, but since cloud-run jobs don't have a VM running constantly there is no endpoint to scrape metrics from.
My intuition tells me is should be possible to push the metric to the google environment but I have not figured out how (or even what to search for).
There are no useful env containing an URL to push to or simulair.
CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT: 0
CLOUD_RUN_EXECUTION: myjob-test-balance-s79pk
CLOUD_RUN_TASK_COUNT: 1
CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX: 0


Here's a tutorial on writing metrics using OpenTelemetry in a sidecar. You can use it as a reference to implement that in a job instead.
